# Special loss function for perspective images

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tf.keras

I am currently working on a project to detect the trackbed of railroads. The images to segemt always have the same camera perspective.

Is there a special loss function that can be used for perspective images or is binary cross entropy the best choice here?
I would like to penalize errors more heavily the nearer they are to the image horizon, because they make up a larger area of the actual track.

[Example image with label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d5GZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can build & train a separate convolutional neural network to determine the loss from the images.
But, you will have to label the loss manually by hand for each image in order to train the network.

You can reduce your efforts of labeling by labeling around 200 images then, by using data augmentation, up-sample it to 1000 images.

Data Augmentation techniques:

1. Change image brightness as a random percentage between 65 & 135
2. Change image contrast as a random percentage between 65 & 135
3. Change image saturation as a random percentage between 65 & 135
4. Horizontal flip.
5. Add Gaussian noise to image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I already use all your augmentations.
I forgot to mention that all pictures are taken with the same camera perspective.
Would the loss still have to be marked on each image?